# Как задать стиль для дней недели в AIR DATEPICKER?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В AIR DATEPICKER [https://air-datepicker.com/ru....не](https://air-datepicker.com/ru....%D0%BD%D0%B5) могу задать стили для дней недели....кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Стилизовать прям проблема. А так вроде неплохой Date Picker

Comment: предположительно просто через инструменты разраба глянуть какие там классы есть и переопределить типо

.air-datepicker--navigation {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}

.air-datepicker-cell.-day-.-selected- {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: red;
}

Comment: const x = new AirDatePicker("#picker", {
      classes: "x",
    });

можно кантейнеру задать класс и отталкиватся от него, также onRenderCell возврашяет classes, но все же думаю просто глянуть на ком какой класс и переопределить, в доках нечего другово не нашел, на всякий деталнее прочесть все.